# How do i make the right side 300px and the left side as big as possible? CSS

Tags: css

Here is some code http://jsfiddle.net/LfC78/

I am trying to make the right side 300px (which is roughly half on my screen. My site will use a different fix width) and the leftside to be the remainder of the width. As you can see, the leftside isnt and the textarea is not readable.

The right side MUST be on the right and not under. Also i possibly will make the min height of both sides the height of the client screen (if its possible with css).

I messed around for an hour without success. How do i do this?

Answer (score 1):

**Option1: CSS**

One way to do it without using JS will be to have a wrapper which will contain entire width of your content and inside it float a block to right side of 300px {or whatever width you require}

**Option2:**
http://pastie.org/1472661/

```
var width = window.innerWidth - 300;
document.getElementById('leftside').style.width = width + 'px';
```

Also, add clear the floating div

```
<div class="Display clrfx">
    <div class="leftside">
    <textarea cols=""></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="rightside">the text</div>
</div>

.clrfx:after {
display:block;
clear:both;
content:"";
}
```

Comment: Option 1 does not work. In fact that is EXACTLY what i did in the link. Option 2 i decided to try. It doesnt appear to work but i most likely did it wrong http://jsfiddle.net/LfC78/35/

Comment: That doesnt work. 1 is too small and 1000 pushes the right side down.

Comment: final code i am using is http://pastie.org/1472653 as you said you are dealing with fixed width, just set the "cols" value to whatever you want so that it touches the rightside

Comment: As nice as pastie is, i like jsfiddle with html. You should learn it. Anyways i tried out the solution and i mean only the right side is fixed. The left side needs to be as big as possible (big difference on my wide 1300px screen a 1600px screen and even more on a 1900 screen) http://jsfiddle.net/9pqsT/ anyways someone else figured out a solution. I like that hack, i hate css now

Answer (score 1):

Corrected:

```
.rightside{ background: gray; width:300px; position: absolute; top: 0px; right: 0px; }

.leftside{position: absolute; right: 0px; padding-right: 300px;}

.leftside textarea{ width: 100%; }

.Display{width: 100%;}
```

Edit looks like this won't actually work with a max-width assignment.

Comment: Was that you who kept hitting update? i notice http://jsfiddle.net/LfC78/34/ and was surpised at the revision number (i usually save once every 10updates). You can click the run button instead. But anyways good answer! good solution!

Comment: Actually it DOESNT work. I only get the left side being the max instead of as big as possible. http://jsfiddle.net/LfC78/36/

Comment: My bad, I updated my answer to work correctly, oversight on my part.

Comment: False alarm, i thought it was right. Then i typed something and realize it was out of view. http://jsfiddle.net/LfC78/39/